# Django m2m field. Through model with multiple foreign keys (fk) to same model type

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I wanted all instances in all tables to have an object instance. A one to one primary key field looked like a good way to do this. Like a small example below.

```
from util.fields import BigAutoField,BigForeignKey
from django.db import models


class Common_document(models.Model):
    pk = models.OneToOneField("Type_object", primary_key=True, related_name="common_document_content_pk")
    author = models.ManyToManyField("Type_object", related_name = 'common_document_author',
                                 limit_choices_to = {"Common_document_author_author":"Type_object"} ,null = True,
                                 through = 'Common_document_author', blank = True)
    #....

class Common_document_author(models.Model):
    pk = models.OneToOneField("Type_object", primary_key=True, related_name="common_document_author_pk")
    document = BigForeignKey("Common_document", related_name='Common_document_author_document')
    author = BigForeignKey("Type_object", related_name='Common_document_author_author')


class Type_object(models.Model):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    #....
    # Some of the fields are m2m
```

However this gave the following error:

> django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>   schema.common_document: Intermediary model Common_document_author has more than
>   one foreign key to Type_object, which is ambiguous and is not permitted.

This error is removed if I comment out the pk field in the document_author table. I guess the error comes because django is not sure witch object FK to use. How do i fix this? Is there a way to tell django which field in the m2m table to be used in the m2m field?

I am probably not going to do it like this. m2m tables are probably not going to need to have an object instance, but I would still like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand you motivation.  Why do you want to use a foreign key as your primary index?  Sure, index it, but primary?.  You might also try changing its name from 'pk', I am sure Django makes assumptions about the field called 'pk'.

Comment: That is not the problem. The same error comes as long as a m2m table has multiple FK to the same object (Topic_object in this example).

Comment: What about specifying the intermediary table with through= or db_table= ?  Maybe django is trying to give the same name to some of the connecting infrastructure.  Also, why does common_doc.author point to the type_object table instead of the common_doc_author table?

Your tables seem a bit more complex than necessary.  What is your motivation for the type_object table?